# Lower bound of way found time complexity

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Let $T$ is a tree graph  with the $N$ vertices and edges of $T$ have integer weights, $M$ is an integer value.

Task is check existing of vertices $a$, $b$ in $T$ with weight of way from $a$ to $b$ in $T$ is $M$.

Question: can this task be solved in $o(N \cdot \log N)$?

Known algorithm has $O(N \cdot \log N)$ time complexity.

Comment: Do you mean the weight of a path from vertex $a$ to vertex $b$ is exactly $M$?  Or at least $M$?   Or at most $M$?

Comment: Exactly M.
Another cases have a solution in $O(N)$

Comment: In negative weights are possible, I don't know solution in O(n) of "at least M" and "at most M" cases...

Comment: Hmm.  Label the cost of every node with an 'X'.  Start at A, label its cost '0'.  Label the parent of A with the cost of the edge from A to the parent.  Label the grand parent of A with the cost of A to the grandparent.  Etc until you reach the root.  Now do the same thing again starting at B, except when you reach a node that is already labeled without an X, you now know the cost of travelling from A to B.  Seems linear time ish. (Some doubt because it isn't a constant space algorithm).

Comment: @DanielV - Linear time for the every vertice, isn't it?

Comment: @DanielV I know only divide-and-conquery method to solve it in $O(N *log(n)$

Comment: @DanielV If I understood the problem correctly, $a$ and $b$ are not fixed; the question asks whether there is *some* pair of vertices whose distance within the graph is exactly $M$.

Comment: @PeterKošinár that would make a lot more sense yes.

Comment: What is the $O(N \log N)$ algorithm you have in mind?

Comment: My guess is that doing this in o instead of O would be worth a Ph.D.